# iOS7 Crash - PopViewController called on a Landscape ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, crash, popviewcontroller

When I call PopViewController on a landscape ViewController a crash occurs. However when i call PopViewController on a Portrait ViewController a crash doesn't occur.

This only occurs on iOS7 - worked fine previously...

> [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];

I'm super stuck on this so any help would be appreciated :)

Here is my Symbolocated Crash Log:

> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 Triggered by Thread:  0
>
> Last Exception Backtrace: 0   CoreFoundation
>     0x2d9b2f4e __exceptionPreprocess + 126
>
> 1   libobjc.A.dylib               0x3801b6aa objc_exception_throw + 34
>
> 2   CoreFoundation                    0x2d9b2e90 +[NSException
>   raise:format:] + 100
>
> 3   UIKit                         0x3020ee70 -[UIViewController
>   _preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentationInWindow:fromInterfaceOrientation:]
>   + 496
>
> 4   UIKit                         0x3020d6ae -[UIWindowController 
>   transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:animation:]
>   + 2054
>
> 5   UIKit                         0x3023ff86 -[UIViewController
>   _dismissViewControllerWithTransition:from:completion:] + 1390
>
> 6   UIKit                         0x301ef1e0 -[UIViewController
>   dismissViewControllerWithTransition:completion:] + 1024
>
> 7   UIKit                         0x303ecae2 -[UINavigationController
>   _popViewControllerAndUpdateInterfaceOrientationAnimated:] + 814 8   UIKit                         0x301ef6de -[UINavigationController
>   _popViewControllerWithTransition:allowPoppingLast:] + 290
>
> 9   MyApp                         0x00087e5a 0x55000 + 208474
>
> 10  MyApp                         0x00088c56 0x55000 + 212054
>
> 11  MyApp                         0x000889aa 0x55000 + 211370
>
> 12  MyApp                         0x000a13f6 0x55000 + 312310
>
> 13  UIKit                         0x3023b540 -[UIWindowController
>   transitionViewDidComplete:fromView:toView:removeFromView:] + 1908
>
> 14  UIKit                         0x3023acf6 __101-[UIWindowController
>   transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:animation:]_block_invoke293
>   + 166
>
> 15  UIKit                         0x3023ac1e
>   -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:] + 70
>
> 16  UIKit                         0x3023ab08 -[UITransitionView
>   notifyDidCompleteTransition:] + 284 17  UIKit
>   0x3023a610 -[UITransitionView _didCompleteTransition:] + 940
>
> 18  UIKit                         0x3015bc32 -[UIViewAnimationState
>   sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 174
>
> 19  UIKit                         0x3015bb4a -[UIViewAnimationState
>   animationDidStop:finished:] + 66
>
> 20  QuartzCore                        0x2fdb3d04
>   CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 228
>
> 21  libdispatch.dylib             0x384fed62 _dispatch_client_callout
>   + 18
>
> 22  libdispatch.dylib             0x385057bc
>   _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 264
>
> 23  CoreFoundation                    0x2d97d81c
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 4
>
> 24  CoreFoundation                    0x2d97c0f0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1296
>
> 25  CoreFoundation                    0x2d8e6ce2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific +
>   518
>
> 26  CoreFoundation                    0x2d8e6ac6 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
>
> 27  GraphicsServices                  0x325b427e GSEventRunModal + 134
>
> 28  UIKit                         0x30188a3c UIApplicationMain + 1132
>
> 29  MyApp                         0x0005ca84 0x55000 + 31364
>
> 30  MyApp                         0x0005ca0c 0x55000 + 31244

Comment: The view controller is definaltly not nil. See screen shot where i am trying to go back to selecttask view controller, my current being speedtapviewcontroller 


See: tinypic.com/r/2qxahl0/5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the reason it crashed on iOS7 was due to a missing piece of code on the previous view controller to tell it to show the next previous page as portrait!

> -(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
>
> ```
> return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

maybe your view controller had killed when you rotate, so when you call popViewControllerAnimated it will make crash.

Comment: The view controller is definaltly not nil. See screen shot where i am trying to go back to selecttask view controller, my current being speedtapviewcontroller

http://tinypic.com/r/2qxahl0/5